# Is there a way to use pre-trained Embedding with Tf-Idf in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I am using the default and basic implementation of Text Classification as:

```
 

  tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size, filters = filters)
  tokenizer.fit_on_texts(list(train_X))
  train_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_X)
  val_X = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_X)
  train_X = pad_sequences(train_X, maxlen=maxlen)
  val_X = pad_sequences(val_X, maxlen=maxlen)

 def get_coefs(word,*arr): return word, np.asarray(arr, dtype='float32') # For loading Embedding

  embeddings_index = dict(get_coefs(*o.split(" ")) for o in open(EMBEDDING_FILE))
  all_embs = np.stack(embeddings_index.values())
  emb_mean,emb_std = all_embs.mean(), all_embs.std()
  embed_dim = all_embs.shape[1]

  word_index = tokenizer.word_index
  vocab_size = min(vocab_size, len(word_index))

  embedding_matrix = np.random.normal(emb_mean, emb_std, (vocab_size, embed_dim)) # vocab_size was nb_words
  for word, i in word_index.items():
      if i >= vocab_size: continue
      embedding_vector = embeddings_index.get(word)
      if embedding_vector is not None: embedding_matrix[i] = embedding_vector
```

It works fine but is there a way to [`texts_to_matrix`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#texts_to_matrix), where there are options like `binart, tfidf, count` etc. Is it possible that I can use them with existing Embeddings?

One possible way could be to use a Multiple Input Model and then Concatenate two inputs at one place. Apart from that, is there any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common approach is to multiply each word vector by its corresponding `tf_idf` score. One often sees this approach in academic papers. You could do something like this:

Create `tfidf` scores:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import gensim.downloader as api
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import collections

def td_idf_word2weight(text):
    print("Creating TfidfVectorizer...")
    tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=' '.join)
    tfidf.fit(text)

    # if a word was never seen - it is considered to be at least as infrequent as any of the known words
    max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)
    return collections.defaultdict(
        lambda: max_idf,
        [(w, tfidf.idf_[i]) for w, i in tfidf.vocabulary_.items()])

text = [['she let the balloon float up into the air with her hopes and dreams'],
        ['the old rusted farm equipment surrounded the house predicting its demise'],
        ['he was so preoccupied with whether or not he could that he failed to stop to consider if he should']]

td_idf = td_idf_word2weight(text)

text = np.concatenate(text)
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
text_sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text)
text_sequences = tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(text_sequences, padding='post')
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
print(td_idf.items())
print(vocab_size)
```

```
Creating TfidfVectorizer...
dict_items([('she', 1.6931471805599454), ('let', 1.6931471805599454), ('the', 1.2876820724517808), ('balloon', 1.6931471805599454), ('float', 1.6931471805599454), ('up', 1.6931471805599454), ('into', 1.6931471805599454), ('air', 1.6931471805599454), ('with', 1.2876820724517808), ('her', 1.6931471805599454), ('hopes', 1.6931471805599454), ('and', 1.6931471805599454), ('dreams', 1.6931471805599454), ('old', 1.6931471805599454), ('rusted', 1.6931471805599454), ('farm', 1.6931471805599454), ('equipment', 1.6931471805599454), ('surrounded', 1.6931471805599454), ('house', 1.6931471805599454), ('predicting', 1.6931471805599454), ('its', 1.6931471805599454), ('demise', 1.6931471805599454), ('he', 1.6931471805599454), ('was', 1.6931471805599454), ('so', 1.6931471805599454), ('preoccupied', 1.6931471805599454), ('whether', 1.6931471805599454), ('or', 1.6931471805599454), ('not', 1.6931471805599454), ('could', 1.6931471805599454), ('that', 1.6931471805599454), ('failed', 1.6931471805599454), ('to', 1.6931471805599454), ('stop', 1.6931471805599454), ('consider', 1.6931471805599454), ('if', 1.6931471805599454), ('should', 1.6931471805599454)])
38
```

Create `tf_idf`-weighted embeddings matrix:

```
model = api.load("glove-twitter-25")
embedding_dim = 25
weight_matrix = np.zeros((vocab_size, embedding_dim))
for word, i in tokenizer.word_index.items():
  try:
    embedding_vector = model[word] * td_idf[word]
    weight_matrix[i] = embedding_vector 
  except KeyError:
    weight_matrix[i] = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, embedding_dim)
print(weight_matrix.shape)
```

```
(38, 25)
```

Comment: Makes Sense. How did I not get that. Multiplying `tf-idf` by Embedding makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you please explain the logic of `max_idf = max(tfidf.idf_)` . I mean `OOV` shouldn't be minimum?

Comment: It’s just one option.. take a look at the docs .. you can can solve it differently also.

Comment: Which docs are you talking about? I did not get that lambda part. Can you please explain how that works in Laymen terms.

Comment: These docs https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html. In the lambda part you are just creating a dictionary where each word represents one key in the dict  and the corresponding tfidf score represents the value of that key. Print out the values if it helps you .

Comment: No, I was looking for the use of `lambda` turns it's just a short cut for `if word in dict` else `some value` like `max` in out case. Thanks

Comment: Just one question here. I have misspelled words too. Which I want to remove. So let's suppose I have used the `vocab_size` as 10. How would I sync `TfIdfVectorizer: min_df` and `Keras: Tokenizer` in that case?