# How to use custom function with tensorflow dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to TensorFlow's `tf.data.Dataset` and I am trying to use it on my data that I loaded with pandas dataframe as follows:

Load the input date (df_input):

```
    id               messages  Label
0   11  I am not driving home   0
1   11      Please pick me up   1
2  103   The car already park   1
3  103     No need for ticket   0
4  104       I will buy a car   1
5  104       I will buy truck   1
```

And I do preprocess and apply text Vectorization as follows:

```
text_vectorizer = layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=20, output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=6)
text_vectorizer.adapt(df_input.message.values.tolist())

def encode(texts):
    encoded_texts = text_vectorizer(texts)
    return encoded_texts.numpy()

train_data = encode(df_input.message.values) ## This the training data
train_label = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(df_input.label.values, 2) ## This labels
```

Then I am using the preprocess data in the training model by using the TensorFlow `tf.data.Dataset` function as follows:

```
train_dataset_df = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
    .shuffle(1000)
    .batch(2)
    )
```

My **question** is how I can **transform** the data in every training **epoch** by applying my custom function to the training data. I saw a usage example of performing the transformation via `.map` function from [here](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/) to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70632285/is-it-possible-to-apply-some-transformation-augmentation-of-text-data-dynamic):

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(2).map(lambda x, y: (text_vectorizer(x), y))
```

My goal is to apply my custom function as follows (which reorders the words in text data):

```
def order_augment_sent(Sentence):
    words = Sentence.split(" ")
    words.sort()
    newSentence = " ".join(words)
    return newSentence


train_dataset_ds = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
    .shuffle(1000)
    .batch(2)
    .map(lambda x, y: (order_augment_sent(x), y))
    )
```

But I am getting error as:

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Or if I apply my other cutom function, I am getting as:

```
TypeError: To be compatible with tf.function, Python functions must return zero or more Tensors or ExtensionTypes or None values; in compilation of <function _tf_if_stmt.<locals>.aug_body at 0124f565>, found return value of type WarningException, which is not a Tensor or ExtensionType.
```

I am not sure how I can do this and I will appreciate it if you have any idea or solution to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you get in your lambda function are token from the vectors so they are int. If you want to reorder the text data, you need to do it before the text_vectorizer.

So you should add the TextVectorization layer to your model so your map function will have the string and you can reorder the sentance before calling the TextVectorization.

Here is an almost working exemple, you just need to edit the order_augment_sent function with the code you need, I didn't know what kind of sorting you want to do, probably you will have to write a custom sort with numpy https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

train_data = ["I am not driving home", "Please pick me up", "The car already park", " No need for ticket", "I will buy a car", "I will buy truck"]
train_label = [0,1,1,0,1,1]

text_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data)
max_features = 5000  # Maximum vocab size.
max_len = 4  # Sequence length to pad the outputs to.

# Create the layer.
vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
 max_tokens=max_features,
 output_mode='int',
 output_sequence_length=max_len)

# Now that the vocab layer has been created, call `adapt` on the text-only
# dataset to create the vocabulary. You don't have to batch, but for large
# datasets this means we're not keeping spare copies of the dataset.
vectorize_layer.adapt(train_data)

# Create the model that uses the vectorize text layer
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Start by creating an explicit input layer. It needs to have a shape of
# (1,) (because we need to guarantee that there is exactly one string
# input per batch), and the dtype needs to be 'string'.
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string))

# The first layer in our model is the vectorization layer. After this
# layer, we have a tensor of shape (batch_size, max_len) containing vocab
# indices.
model.add(vectorize_layer)

def apply_order_augment_sent(s):
    Sentence = s.decode('utf-8')
    words = Sentence.split(" ")
    words.sort()
    newSentence = " ".join(words)
    return(newSentence)

def order_augment_sent(x: np.ndarray, y:np.ndarray):
    new_x = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
      new_x.append(np.array([apply_order_augment_sent(x[i])]))
      
    print('new', new_x, y)
    return(new_x, y)



train_dataset_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_data, train_label))
train_dataset_ds = train_dataset_ds.shuffle(1000).batch(32)
train_dataset_ds = train_dataset_ds.map(lambda item1, item2: tf.numpy_function(
          order_augment_sent, [item1, item2], [tf.string, tf.int32]))

list(train_dataset_ds.as_numpy_iterator())


model.predict(train_dataset_ds)
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. Yes, it makes sense now. So, would you please give some code example that helps me to understand? i am new in tf here and I am wondering if I can do this custom function process in every epoch? thanks

Comment: I'll try something, I'll edit the answer when it's good

Comment: Thank you so much and look forward to it.

Comment: I added some code @Bilgin, only problem is the map_func, it's a bit tricky to write it the way u want

Comment: Thank you for the code example. It is fine if you have any other way to do this or if you have any suggestions. When I run your code, I am getting errors as: ```Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 2```

Comment: If you want to apply at each epoch and use tensorflow dataset you need to make your lambda function work. Try to comment it in my code to see the result we expect

Comment: @Bilgin I post a version of the code that I think does what you want, becareful about the batch(1), I make it work string by string

Comment: Thank you. This is great. I also updated my question based on your comments. I would appreciate it if you please let me know if my model is correct based on your suggestion (using vec layer inside the model). Also, is there any way to save/print the augmented data in every epoch? I am interested to see if data actually transform in every epoch. Thank you so much

Comment: Also, do this code only works with batch(1)? Is there anyway to make it work with other larger batches such as 32?

Comment: @Bilgin you can check how it works by printing the new sentance inside your order_augment_sent function

Comment: @Bilgin I tried a version with larger batch, tell me if it works for u

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. This works great. My only question is if you have time: when I run your code, looks like there are two sets of data loading to the model (as printed). To observe this, I change the ```words.sort()``` to ```np.random.shuffle(words)``` and shows two different sets of ``` new [array([' ...')]```. Thank you.

Comment: Yes I think you should add the layer inside the model, for more information https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers#preprocessing_data_before_the_model_or_inside_the_model

Comment: I didn't understand your questions about the 2 sets of data. Maybe this answer fix your first question, about transforming data at each epoch, maybe it will be better to check this answer and create a new question for your next problems (like where to put the TextVectorization) maybe some other people of the community can help and don't do it now because it seems a bit messy.